# Do clients of a SQL Server 2008 need to be on a Network domain or can they also be in a workgroup?

Tags: sql-server-2008

When we install a SQL Server 2008 on the Windows 2008 server and the SQL clients on the PC's in the network, is there any pre-requisite that these clients should only be on a Domain controller network and not on a workgroup ?

The vendor who is installing this claims that it has to be a PDC based network whereas we feel the workgroup configuration should also work ?

Thanks.

Chak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that MS SQL Server 2008 will work just fine without being on domain type network (we use this setup in our dev environment).

Just out of curiosity, did the vendor give you some specific reasons for why this would be needed?

Comment: Thanks. I am yet to get their reason.